# How to select column and it's max

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table like:

```
ID     Value 
1       123    
2       321    
3       31     
4       234   
5       123    
6       32     
7       77
```

What I need to get is a table with additional column:

```
ID     Value    Maximum
1       123       321
2       321       321
3       31        321
4       234       321
5       123       321
6       32        321
7       77        321
```

But I have no idea how I should build a query.

Answer (score 2):

Join your table with a subquery that gets the maximum.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t2.maximum
FROM yourTable AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(value) AS maximum FROM yourTable) AS t2
```

Comment: Deleted my answer and gave you +1. :-)